# MongoDB / Mongoid embedded document loading with ror

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I have a document (DataSet) with many embedded documents (DataPoint) (1:N relation). Since this appears as an array to me in rails, if I want to read every 20th element for example, will it load every element into memory, or only every 20th element?

I am trying to figure out if this will be inefficient. I would like ideally only to load what I need from the DB.

Here is an example:

```
a = DataSet.first
points = a.data_points.values_at(*(0..a.data_points.count).step(20))
```

Is this bad? Is there a mongoid specific way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Embedded documents aren't relations (in the typical RDBMS fashion) but are actually embedded (hence the name) within the parent record, just like any other attribute. So when you call `DataSet.first`, you're loading the entire document, as well as its embedded records, into memory.

Depending on how your application is structured, you may see a benefit from denormalizing every 20th `DataPoint` into a separate embedded relation (during a callback, or in a background task, or something like that), and then when you load the document, load only those points with `DataSet.only(:datapoints_sample).first` - which will load only that relation into memory (and no other attributes).